# I am not find any sandbox environment at developer portal ui to create bot twitter(X) to activate webhook

Tags: twitter

I want to create bot on twitter and need to activate webhook ,Due to frequently changes in twitter. The use for developer portal for webhook api become very difficult to use: we are not able to set/change dev environment due to missing of dev environment section at devloper potal. This link is also not working: https://developer.twitter.com/en/account/environments 7 Please help me with alternative or any way to use webbook api for free/basic plan

to create dev environment to register webhook twitter.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I need to create bot on Twitter and i created a developer app from a developer account Twitter i need to create a dev environment to use activity APIs to register webhook i need to help